# why CGContextSaveGState is not required even after several modification to the current context?

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I am really strugggling with Quartz2D for more then 10 days please help me understand few concepts I will be really grateful, please look at this code and screenshot url.

This code draw image with border and write text to it and the image become whole new image with border and text.

```
//part 1 
CGSize cgs = CGSizeMake(250.0, 400.0);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(cgs);

CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(0,0,cgs.width,cgs.height);
CGRect imageRect = CGRectInset(rectangle, 5.4, 5.4);
imageRect.size.height -= 100;

UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BMW.jpg"]; 
[myImage drawInRect:imageRect];    

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 10.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
CGContextStrokeRect(context, rectangle);
//



//part 2

 1. CGRect contextRect = rectangle;
 2. CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, contextRect.size.height);
 3. CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1, -1);
 4. float w, h;
 5. w = contextRect.size.width;
 6. h = contextRect.size.height;
 7. CGContextSelectFont (context, "Helvetica-Bold", 25,
    kCGEncodingMacRoman);
 8. CGContextSetCharacterSpacing (context, 5);
 9. CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
 10. CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
 11. CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context, 45, 50, "Quartz 2D", 9);

//



//part 3
UIImage *testImg =  UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

[testImg drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(35, 10)];
//
```

http://i40.tinypic.com/140aptv.png

part 1 and part 3 of the code is very clear to me

**problem is regarding part 2**

> on line 2 and 3 coordinates are transformed so the text do not display
>   upside down, but uiimage already take care of this internally, why it
>   didn't transformed to upside down? why it is still displaying in
>   correct position after transform is applied for text using same
>   context? I am asking this because when uiimage coordinates are already
>   modified then this coordinate transform will not make uiimage again
>   upside down?
>
> on line 9 and 10 fillcolor and strokecolor methods are called and
>   fillcolor changes the text color, but strokecolor not doing any thing
>   to text why? And why without CGContextSaveGState it modified the
>   color of text not the border color?
>
> regarding these both points I mentioned above the common confusion is
>   why its working perfectly why this code didn't need
>   CGContextSaveGState and CGContextRestoreGState. How it is possible
>   that context is modified and it didn't effect the perviously drawing
>   item like blue border in this case and coordinates transformation for
>   text.

Please correct me if I am lacking in any way to make you understand my points.

Thanks in advance,
Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quartz 2D uses the "painter's model." That means, you draw one thing, and it's done. Then you draw another thing, and it goes on top of what you drew before. Then you draw another thing and that goes on top, etc. If I pick up a stamp, dip it in paint and press it to paper, then turn it over and do it again to another part of the paper, the first stamped image doesn't flip over just because I flipped the stamp.

Every time you see "stroke" or "draw," you're modifying the final image. Later changes to the context don't effect that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, But if this is the case then why we need CGContextSaveGState and CGContextRestoreGState? and what will happen I want to draw one image rotated and another normally means no rotation.

Comment: You need CGContextSaveCGState to handle cases where you want to go back to an old state. This is most common in functions that do some drawing for you (and might leave your context in a strange state otherwise). Also common in loops. CGContextSaveCGState is also useful in the case you mention where you want one rotated, then you restore the context and draw the second one without rotation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, its really helpful, but I am still little bit confused between painter model and saving graphics state :) need to do more practice. It will be really awesome if you can refer me any quartz2D tutorial, I am unable to find any useful tutorial on net. Once again thank you for the awesome help.

Comment: The best place for this specific question (and several others) is the Quartz 2D Programming Guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_overview/dq_overview.html

Comment: Chapter 6 of iOS:PTL (http://iosptl.com) goes into this at length. It's targeted at developers with some prior background in iOS, but if you have that then Ch6 includes extensive discussion of contexts and CGContextSaveGState vs UIGraphicsPushcontext, as well as many ways to improve Core Graphics performance and appearance.

Comment: I have been reading this apple guide again an again for past several days but still struggling to wrap my head around this.

Comment: I don't know any really good online tutorials. But there is also the definitive book on the subject, Programming with Quartz. It's pretty dated now and was written for Mac, but it's still a very good book. http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Quartz-Graphics-Kaufmann-Computer/dp/0123694736